# Trying to find this exact type of T Ruler?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, tools

I am trying to find the exact tool which i assume is a modified t ruler to purchase but i cannot see any exactly like it. Any help would be appreciated:

Picture attached:

[image]

It is adjustable and has a fixed right angle piece on top so it is square with the material you are marking. All the t rulers i find only are essentially a standard ruler with an adjustable moving piece. I need the T ruler with the t at the top and then the adjustable moving part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking "product recommendation or places to purchase". See [On-topic](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider this to be an identification question related to engineering, rather than a product recommendation question.

A search using "scriber and depth gauge" presents a large number of inappropriate devices and a smaller number of what appear to be the right device:

[image: scriber depth gauge]

As one might note, this is not of the same scale, but appears to be an accurate match.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcO-WNlVnh8) presents one method to construct a scriber and depth gauge or the same smaller scale. One could expect it is thus possible to build at a larger scale.

Searching for larger versions was fruitless, but only a short period of time was used for the search.

Comment: There are many specialist places that will sell these measuring instruments - just needs some effort in research.